# How to make LookAt align the transform.up vector instead of transform.forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, artificial-intelligence

The problem is that i cannot make a script that makes the enemy rotate so that "up" is pointing against the player, (with that i mean so that it will come to the player with transform.up) And i have not found any working solution yet, (from what i can tell)

I am trying to make a small 2D game, just for my friends to play. What i have tried is making the enemy look at the player and then set the "z" rotation to the same as the "x" rotation and after that reset the "x" and "y" rotation (so that "up" is pointing at the player). But the enemy just goes straight up.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;  // The Transform of the Player that you can controll
    public float MoveSpeed = 4; // How fast the enemy should go
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.LookAt(Player);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, 0, transform.rotation.x);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, transform.rotation.z);
        transform.position += transform.up * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    }
}
```

So what i want to happen is that the Enemy will move to the Player but the rotation part is not working and it just goes straight up in the air instead of following the player. I might just be stupid and have missed something simple...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, 0, transform.rotation.x);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, transform.rotation.z);
```

both times you **overwrite** the rotation with new values additionally mixing Euler (`Vector3`) with [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) fields ... `transform.rotation.x` is **not** the pure rotation around the `X`-axis you see in the Unity inspector.

---

It depends a bit on how exactly you want the `enemy` rotated in the end but you could simply use [`Transform.RotateAround`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) like

```
transform.LookAt(Player);
transform.RotateAround(transform.position, transform.right, 90);
```

`LookAt` by default results in a rotation such that `transform.forward` is pointing at the target, `transform.right` remains pointing right(ish) and `transform.up` remains pointing up(ish). So all you have to do is rotating around that local X-axis `transform.right` exactly `90°` so now `transform.forward` points down instead and `transform.up` points at the target.

which results in

[image]

---

If you than also want to change the other axis you can still additionally rotate it around the local `transform.up` axis as well e.g. to flip the `forward` vector "upwards":

```
transform.LookAt(Player);
transform.RotateAround(transform.position, transform.right, 90);
transform.RotateAround(transform.position, transform.up, 180);
```

---

Is there actually a special reason why you are doing that in `FixedUpdate` and not rather in `Update`? `FixedUpdate` should only be used for Physics related stuff.